# Large strings to double (no scientific notation)

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, double

I was wondering if there is a way to convert this string:

> "-179769313486232000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

into a double value (the number represents `double.MinValue`).
The normal ways of doing it (`TryParse`, `double.Convert`…) do not work as it is too big.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: [*In addition, attempting to parse the string representation of either MinValue or MaxValue throws an OverflowException, as the following example illustrates...*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx)